# Não conecta no banco de dados e não retorna nenhum erro

Tags: mysql

Olá, eu fiz meu site pelo xampp no windows, quando fui migrar para o ubunto percebi que simplesmente o mysql não funcionava, e nem retornava erro nenhum, por exemplo, na pagina inicial do site eu já uso o `mysqli_connect`, mesmo com o usuário errado não retorna erro algum.

Não é necessário mostrar código, por que no xampp funciona perfeitamente.

Fazendo a conexão:

```
$conn = mysqli_connect(SQL_HOST, SQL_USUARIO, SQL_SENHA, SQL_BANCO);
```

Answer (score 0):

Adiciona as seguintes linhas, para obteres o erro:

```
// verificar a conexão
if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
  echo "Falha ao conectar ao servidor: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Resolvido o problema, na verdade olhando o log descobri que o mysql foi mal instalado, apenas reinstalei e tudo funcionou certinho.